# Accessing values from multiple lists in a variable

Tags: python, list, turtle-graphics

In python. Say I have a function that takes 1 argument, sky.

`sky = [a, b, c],[d, e, f],[g, h, i]`

How can I access, say, the 'd' value when I make my function. I'm using turtle so:
eg of what I want.

```
def skyline(sky):
    setheading(90)
    forward(d pixels)
```

But replacing 'd pixels' with d's actual value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to dynamically get the value?

The obvious, static answer it seems you're looking for is: `sky[1][0]`.

Comment: Thanks. I get it now. I was trying to use forward([1][0]) but now I realise it has to be forward(sky[1][0]). Silly me.